# How to use EF Core when two properties in the principle entity point to the same attribute in the dependent entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have 2 model classes:

`Department.cs`

```cs
public class Department
{
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FacultyId")]
    public IList<Faculty> Faculties{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FacultyId")]
    public Faculty HOD { get; set; }
}
```

`Faculty.cs`

```cs
public class Faculty
{
    public string FacultyId { get; set; }
    
    public string FacultyName { get; set; }
    public FacultyStatus FacultyStatus { get; set; }
    public Designation Designation { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
    public string Qualifications { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Department Department{ get; set; }
}
```

I am having trouble determining how to set the HOD for the department. What I thought of was, making the HOD column a foreign key, but I don't know how good or useful that would be.

I referred to [this link](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/53275214/one-to-one-multiple-foreign-key-from-same-table-ef-core) to learn, but I am unable to apply the same.

I'm getting an error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Department.Faculties' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: So you have a 1-many relationship *and* a 1-1 relationship with one of those rows? You can either add a `Department.HODId` foreign key for your 1-1 relationship. Or skip the relationship and add a flag column to your `Faculty` instead.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman *So you have a 1-many relationship and a 1-1 relationship with one of those rows?* Yes, precisely :)

Comment: *You can either add a Department.HODId foreign key for your 1-1 relationship. Or skip the relationship and add a flag column to your Faculty instead.* Like this? -> `[ForeignKey("FacultyId")]
public int HODId { get; set; }
public Faculty HOD { get; set; }` Because I've tried this. It returns the same error

Comment: Since you have 2 relationships, you can't rely on conventions, you must explicitly specify all FK metadata. Or use the fluent api to configure everything. eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=data-annotations%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, um... I'm kinda stuck: *The [InverseProperty] attribute on property 'Department.Faculties' is not valid. The property 'FK_Faculties' is not a valid navigation on the related type 'Faculty'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation.* Would you mind converting your comment to an answer and give an exampe?